# Add OnClicked listener to AActor in UE 4.18

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I am trying to add an event listener to an actor so that I can preform certain tasks when the actor is clicked on in the game. I have tried multiple things including OnClicked.Add, OnClicked.AddDynamic and multiple versions of each that I saw in other answers but they all end up not compiling and giving a similar error.

Here is my current class

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project 
Settings.

#include "InterestItem1.h"


// Sets default values
AInterestItem1::AInterestItem1()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to 
    improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AInterestItem1::BeginPlay()
    {
    Super::BeginPlay();
    OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, AInterestItem1::moveToItem);

}

// Called every frame
void AInterestItem1::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

void AInterestItem1::moveToItem(UPrimitiveComponent* ClickedComp, FKey 
ButtonPressed){
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("meh, they clicked me"));
}
```

with this I am getting the following error in VS
no instance of function template "FActorOnClickedSignature::_Internal_AddDynamic" matches the argument list

and this compile error in the output log

```
CompilerResultsLog: Error: C:\Users\AtLink\Documents\Unreal Projects\Axis_Test_Purged\Source\Axis_Test_Purged\InterestItem1.cpp(18) : error C3867: 'AInterestItem1::moveToItem': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
CompilerResultsLog: Error: C:\Users\AtLink\Documents\Unreal Projects\Axis_Test_Purged\Source\Axis_Test_Purged\InterestItem1.cpp(18) : error C2672: 'TBaseDynamicMulticastDelegate<FWeakObjectPtr,void,AActor *,FKey>::__Internal_AddDynamic': no matching overloaded function found
CompilerResultsLog: ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\AtLink\Documents\Unreal Projects\Axis_Test_Purged\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Axis_Test_Purged-4805.dll
```

I'm new to unreal so I could use some simple explanations of what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your BeginPlay method in line

```
OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, AInterestItem1::moveToItem);
```

> error C3867: 'AInterestItem1::moveToItem': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

You should create a pointer to member and pass it to AddDynamic like so:

```
OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &AInterestItem1::moveToItem);
```

> error C2672: 'TBaseDynamicMulticastDelegate::__Internal_AddDynamic': no matching overloaded function found

This error also shows, that there is no AddDynamic function that takes the arguments you passed.

There are plenty of examples on the web, for example:

[AddDynamic example](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/134502/adddynamic-not-working.html)

I have used this in my own project also:

```
    // Sets default values
AArea::AArea()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    USphereComponent* SphereComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
    RootComponent = SphereComponent;

    this->StaticMeshComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponent"));
    this->StaticMeshComponent->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &AArea::SelectArea);
}

void AArea::SelectArea(AActor* TouchedActor, FKey ButtonPressed) {
    PlayerController->ChangeSelectedArea(this);
}
```

Be sure to read a documentation about delegates here:

[Unreal Engine Delegates](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/index.html)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, the link to delegate looks very helpful. I've already looked at numerous examples on the web and that's where I got the code I have but all of them produced the error C2672: 'TBaseDynamicMulticastDelegate::__Internal_AddDynamic': no matching overloaded function found, Error when I tried them. Is there a specific example you could link to that you know works?

Comment: I have edited the answer, the UE version I use is 4.18.3.

Comment: Yes!!! I've just found this answer. Hopefully  more UE questions are comming. UE4 Forum really sucks

Comment: @Hani Thanks, I was able to bet it to compile using this but still not calling the function(I don't see the log printout. Is it possible that there is a project setting or something that needs to be changed?

Comment: @PaulB Have you enabled click events in editor or in your GameMode? Try to debug your project with a breakpoint inside your moveToItem function, to check if you receive click events at all. Also, check this link

[Logging in UE4](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Logs,_Printing_Messages_To_Yourself_During_Runtime)

and try to change the log level to something that writes to console. Remember to look out for logs in correct place, as different level mostly means writing logs to different place.